# Configure help output in Pry

Tags: ruby, pry

Is there a way to customize the help system in [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)?

What I want is to display description from my [custom commands](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Custom-commands). Right now all of the Pry help documentation is printed when `help` is entered in the REPL.

For example:

Current help output:

```
Help
  help               Show a list of commands or information about a specific command

Context
  cd                 Move into a new context (object or scope).
  find-method        Recursively search for a method within a Class/Module or the current namespace.
  ls                 Show the list of vars and methods in the current scope.

 etc...
```

What I would like is to remove the Pry help listings:

```
Commands
  my-custom-command  description
  my-custom-command2 description

etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

"edit help" will edit the command on disk on lib/pry/. It's not a very portable solution! :)
Pry has a concept of "command sets", a grouping of commands. The default command set can be found at Pry.commands. The cool thing about the command set is that you can take commands away, or add new ones :)

The CommandSet API isn't great. You can't say Pry.commands["help"] = other_command. You can say this, though:

```
# Solution 1 (add a Pry::ClassCommand).
Pry.commands.delete "help"
Pry.commands.add_command MyHelpCommand

# Solution 2 (replaces Pry's help with a Pry::BlockCommand).
Pry.commands.command "help" do
  output.puts "Helpin'"
end
```

This API could definitely use some work. It would be nice if #[]= would work but it'd need some work - commands encapsulate their name when they are created. the key would need to be reassigned as the commands name. If you're trying to mix and match different pry commands you should definitely check out Pry::CommandSet.

Comment: pull request to add CommandSet#[]=: https://github.com/pry/pry/pull/979 - left an example on how it would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are in luck, as it is simply Ruby.

Go ahead and type `edit help` and it will open up the Pry class for editing.  Modify away!

Of course, you are welcome to fork the project, make your changes, create the gem and install it on your system with your customization.

Comment: I'm using Pry as a REPL in a gem and want to configure it before my gem loads.

Comment: Right on. Modify PRY and then create a gem for your modified PRY.  And use your modified PRY for your REPL in that gem.  Pretty much the answer describes doing this.

Comment: I would like to avoid forking Pry to do this. I'm guessing there isn't a way to configure Pry out of the box.

Comment: Yes, there is.  Write a gem, that uses PRY's namespace, require your gem to "monkey patch" Pry.  Or just require your library without creating a gem.  Either way, yes, you can change it, you can configure it.  But your "configuration" of changing the help system is not a "configuration option"  It is a feature. Write the feature.